# List available topic on MQTT connection with paho

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt

I've got ay MQTT client setup with Paho, and the broker I'm connecting to publishes a topic of `device/****/report`

The issue is that **** is actually a dynamic value, and is actually the serial number of the device that I need to pull into my code.

Is there anyway that in the on_connect method of paho, I can fetch the published topics so that I can parse this serial number?

```
def try_connection(
    user_input: dict[str, Any],
) -> bool:
    """Test if we can connect to an MQTT broker."""
    # We don't import on the top because some integrations
    # should be able to optionally rely on MQTT.
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt  # pylint: disable=import-outside-toplevel

    client = mqtt.Client()
    result: queue.Queue[bool] = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)

    def on_connect(
        client_: mqtt.Client,
        userdata: None,
        flags: dict[str, Any],
        result_code: int,
        properties: mqtt.Properties | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        """Handle connection result."""
        LOGGER.debug(f"client: {client.__dict__}")
        LOGGER.debug(f"flags: {flags}")
        LOGGER.debug(f"result_code: {result_code}")
        LOGGER.debug(f"properties: {properties}")
        result.put(result_code == mqtt.CONNACK_ACCEPTED)

    client.on_connect = on_connect

    client.connect_async(user_input[CONF_HOST], 1883)
    client.loop_start()

    try:
        return result.get(timeout=5)
    except queue.Empty:
        return False
    finally:
        client.disconnect()
        client.loop_stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, topics only exist at the point a message is published to them.

What you can use the MQTT topic wildcards.

MQTT supports 2 types of wildcard.

- `#` which has to appear at the end of a topic patten and can match multiple topic sections. e.g. `foo/#` matches `foo/bar` and `foo/bar/baz`
- `+` which matches a single topic element and can appear anywhere in the topic. e.g. `foo/+/bar` matches `foo/one/bar` and `foo/HelloWorld/bar`

Both can only match whole topic sections, not part of them e.g. `foo/ba#` or `foo/ba+/baz` are both not valid.

So you can subscribe to `device/+/report` and you will get reports from all the devices, but you will have to parse each topic at the point messages are published to determine which device published it.

Comment: Ah OK.  I added the code I have in, as initially, this is just testing it can make the MQTT connection.  I guess what I'll have to do here is to subscribe to `device/#` and then put a while loop in.  Once it's received a message, use the on_message function to get the topic, set a complete var to true and end the while?

Comment: No, that really will not work. You need to change your whole understanding here, MQTT is totally Asynchronous. You can't make a synchronous call that will get you a list of device, it just doesn't work that way.